# Ubuntu: screenshot and edit tools

Tags: screenshot

I am looking for a tool that can be used to screenshot and edit. I found this application called **[shutter](http://shutter-project.org/)** I have installed it, but it does not edit. I have tried to fix the problem with no success.

Do you know any tool that with these two features (screenshot and edit)?

thanks!

Comment: You can easily re-enable the "edit" option: https://askubuntu.com/a/1119283/323310

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using Kolourpaint and its great one!

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install kolourpaint
```

[image]

Comment: I am taking screenshot with prt sc button, paste is to kolourpaint and edit. I hope my solution will help you.

Comment: O_o seriously? new 139 packages, "147 MB of additional disk space will be used"!

Answer (score 65):

Very useful and light screenshot app for Linux is [Flameshot](https://github.com/lupoDharkael/flameshot) - it provide easy and quick interface for making and editing screenshot, save it, copy to clipboard and upload to imgur.com via single click or hotkeys.

[image]

Comment: This is nice except that it doesn't allow the addition of text.

Comment: I'm going to notice that this application doesn't install on ubuntu 16.04, in fact, it runs on 18.04+. However, by [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1190181/772449) you can compile it on the earlier versions of ubuntu and use it well.

Comment: @yogesnsamy, addition of text is allowed. https://i.imgur.com/UDOYAG5.png

Comment: The best tool I've ever seen. Everything is in its place. Free and open source.

Comment: For ubuntu: `sudo apt install flameshot`. https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot#installation

Comment: To use print key remove the shortcut with ``gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screenshot '[]'`` and add new one in setting under keyboard shortcuts with command ``/usr/bin/flameshot gui``

Answer (score 9):

> > You can directly take Screenshot by below shortcut for the different purpose

**print** Take a Screenshot

**Alt+Print** Take a Screenshot of window

**Shift+Print** Take a Screenshot of an area

**Ctrl+Print** Copy a Screenshot to the clipboard

**Ctrl+Alt+Print** Copy a Screenshot of a window to the clipboard

**Shift+Alt+Print** Copy a Screenshot of an area to the clipboard

> > I suggest gimp to edit image in ubuntu. it is more powerful compare to kolourpaint. to install gimp you have to run below command in terminal. you no more need to add ppa for installing gimp. you can look more details at https://www.gimp.org/

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Answer (score 6):

I have found [ksnip](https://github.com/ksnip/ksnip) - very good screenshot tool with edit and annotate features, that available on Linux/Windows/MacOS! It have classic user interface, based on Qt, and all modern features, such as editing, cropping, annotate with arrows and text (with allow to drag/edit later), upload to imgur.com, etc.
[image: ksnip screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

Very useful and simple screenshot utility is *deepin-screenshot*

```
sudo apt install deepin-screenshot
```

It is much alike as *Lightshot* app on Mac and Windows you can freely select and edit screenshot area.

[image]

Comment: This is nice! Thank you for sharing

Comment: Is this project still in support? Because I've had really hard time trying to install it + github repo is now archieved

Answer (score 2):

**Shutter** is great!

But the "edit" option is somehow disable after installing. To re-enable it, follow the quick solution here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1119283/323310

Answer (score 0):

Press the **Print Screen key** on your keyboard.
[image]

Click on *Area* under *Capture Mode* and select *Rectangular Region*. This will allow you to capture a specific region. Tap *Enter* once you select the region. Use the *Annotate* to edit the screen capture as you would like.

PS: *Flameshot* doesn't work for Kubuntu. Correct me if I'm wrong :)

Answer (score -2):

For a long time, SHUTTER has been a grest screenshot editor+ in LINUX.

But, PhotoScape (3.7) installed in wine, is much better than SHUTTER in many functions.

Who once experenced PhotoScape (3.7) should never use again SHUTTER.

I strongly recommend to replace SHUTTER with PhotoScape (3.7).installed in wine.

To download PhotoScape (3.7) go to http://www.photoscape.org/ps/main/download.php

Refer to https://blog.naver.com/limnyh/221488646884