# How to enable the Edit button in Shutter?

Tags: 18.04, shutter

I am trying to enable the Edit button in Shutter. I installed the application from Ubuntu Software and are using Ubuntu 18.04.

After taking a screenshot the Edit button is disabled. And when hovering the mouse pointer over the button the text "Goo::Canvas/libgoo-canvas-perl needs to be installed for this feature" is shown.

[image]

I have tried to install the package libgoocanvas2-perl and restarted the computer, but the edit button is still not enabled:

```
sudo apt install libgoocanvas2-perl
```

That is the only package I can find.

Anyone that knows how to fix this?

Comment: A bug report for this issue has been filed check the status on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shutter/+bug/1767807 to see if an official fix is available

Comment: Great answer and writeup: https://itsfoss.com/shutter-edit-button-disabled/

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I found a solution here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/04/fix-edit-option-disabled-shutter-ubuntu-18-04/.
I can confirm that it works for Budgie 18.04.

> 1. Download and install the [`libgoocanvas-common`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgoocanvas-common_1.0.0-1_all.deb) and [`libgoocanvas3`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgoocanvas3_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb) packages.
>
>    *Either use Gdebi package installer (available in Ubuntu Software) or
>      run command in terminal (press Ctrl+Alt+T) to install the package:*
>
>    ```
>    sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/libgoocanvas3_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb
>    sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/libgoocanvas-common_1.0.0-1_all.deb
>    sudo apt-get -f install
>    ```
> 2. Finally download & install [`libgoo-canvas-perl`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgoo-canvas-perl_0.06-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb) package:
>
>    Also install the package via Gdebi or terminal command, since Ubuntu Software doesn’t solve dependencies automatically:
>
>    ```
>    sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/libgoo-canvas-perl_0.06-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
>    sudo apt-get -f install
>    ```
>
> To apply changes, kill Shutter process or restart your computer!

Comment: budgie, I tested it in Lubuntu 18.04 and it worked, too! Great!

Comment: This solution worked on kde plasma as well.

Comment: I had to install "libgoocanvas-common" before "libgoocanvas3". Otherwise, fab! Let this stand as an example of how to write a great answer! Just spell it all out. Wish i could give you more than one upvote!

Comment: Shutter can not be killed by `killall` it will not complete `shutter` on tab because it is ran under perl process. So it is needed to `killall perl`, or, more safe `ps ax | grep shutter` then `kill <shutter PID>`.

Comment: How about adding the (official?) [shutter PPA](https://launchpad.net/~shutter/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) (which seems to also contain the libgoo libs) and do it all in `sudo apt-get install libgoocanvas-common libgoo...`?  *Update*: apparently a bad idea: various errors around the liboo packages... PPA appears in poor shape.

Comment: In my ubuntu16.04->upgraded_to->ubuntu18.04, the firefox `gdebi-gtk` and `dpkg -i` didnt were enough, and I've had to install the .deb files with console `sudo gdebi ./xxx.deb` which resolved package conflicts (asking first) and completely installed the 3 of them. I guess this probably has to do with being an 16.04_upgraded_to_18.04 (some weird things also happended with vim dependencies)

Comment: Good answer. Works for me. This answer closely resembles this tutorial: https://itsfoss.com/shutter-edit-button-disabled/. Note that to "kill Shutter process" you can use `sudo killall shutter`, as the tutorial I linked to above states. That worked for me too!

Comment: it works for me(Elementary OS).

Comment: This solution worked. Thank you!

Comment: This answer + [This Link](https://itsfoss.com/shutter-edit-button-disabled/) helped me

Comment: Install libgoocanvas-common_1.0.0-1_all.deb first, after it libgoocanvas3_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb

Comment: Already followed the answer, it doesn't work.. purging and reinstalling shutter than it's work.. But why ??

Comment: after reading dozens of blogs on how to do this and still not able to get it to work.. this answer finally solved it. thanks!

Answer (score 51):

There is unofficial PPA with newer version of Shutter plus the required dependencies for Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10. See https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/10/shutter-removed-from-ubuntu-1810-and.html

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/shutter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install shutter
```

and restart Shutter.

Comment: This is the better solution in my opinion.

Comment: didn't work for me no Edit button

Comment: Doesn't give me a working *Edit* button either.

Comment: Make sure your restart Shutter after installing it from the PPA.

Comment: THANK YOU! I uninstalled shutter, added this PPA, restarted, updated and reinstalled--works perfectly.

Comment: It works - make sure to restart Shutter. If previous instance is still running, you won't get the plugins refreshed.

Comment: **restart shutter** is not really a good instruction. Better would be: `pkill shutter` then open shutter again. Like this it worked for me, as closing it is not enough (an instance still runs in the background)

Comment: @firepol 's note completes this solution to 100% working one. Thanks to all.

Comment: Can confirm that @firepot's comment is correct. Shutter doesn't appear to completely close when you exit, but runs in the background. You have to kill it to properly get the new version to load.

Answer (score 13):

Thanks to the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/1029085/75166) of  [budgie](https://askubuntu.com/users/823121/budgie). That solution worked fine for me as well.

Just to clarify in this thread, this is what I did:

1. Downloaded these three packages in Chrome:
   [libgoocanvas-common_1.0.0-1_all.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgoocanvas-common_1.0.0-1_all.deb)
   [libgoocanvas3_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgoocanvas3_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb)
   [libgoo-canvas-perl_0.06-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgoo-canvas-perl_0.06-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb)
2. Clicked on the downloaded files in Chrome (or File Browser) and installed the package with Ubuntu Software.
3. Restarted the computer and then the Edit button was enabled.

Comment: You don't have to restart the computer. Just kill the Shutter process.

Answer (score 9):

**How to fix this in a Snap!** (Dad joke)
Another option, if you don't feel comfortable installing dependencies that aren't in the repo or adding a ppa, is to use the snap package.

You can search for Shutter in the Ubuntu Software store. There should be two packages: the snap and the old package with missing dependencies. To tell which is which, click on each one and go down to the details section. Under Details, make sure the Source says "Snap Store" (and not ubuntu-bionic-universe). Then go back to the top, and click the Install button. Oh snap! You're done.

To install from terminal, simply type:

```
sudo snap install shutter
```

To test it out: launch Shutter, take a screenshot, and test out the Edit functionality. If this was helpful, please consider an up-vote. Thanks!

PS: At the time of writing this, the package in the store was on version 0.94-1. The snap was on version 0.94.3, which is the newest release at https://launchpad.net/shutter #winning

Comment: Best solution!!

Comment: good solution. I agree with that.

Comment: love the dad joke :)

Answer (score 2):

Quick solution, just copy and paste these to your terminal:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgoocanvas-common_1.0.0-1_all.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgoocanvas3_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgoo-canvas-perl_0.06-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgoocanvas-common_1.0.0-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgoocanvas3_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgoo-canvas-perl_0.06-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo apt -f install
```

Then **restart Shutter** and enjoy!

More details here:
https://medium.com/@thucnc/how-to-enable-edit-option-in-shutter-on-ubuntu-18-04-e8b2c8dcc58

Comment: didn't work for me - no Edit button

Comment: @scythargon what version of Ubuntu do you have, and can you share the output of the commands?

Comment: thank you I've already managed to do this somehow

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: How the author located the correct deb file in launchpad?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to other answers here after you install required dependencies

[libgoocanvas-common_1.0.0-1_all.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgoocanvas-common_1.0.0-1_all.deb)
 [libgoocanvas3_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgoocanvas3_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb)
 [libgoo-canvas-perl_0.06-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgoo-canvas-perl_0.06-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb)

You need to kill and restart the shutter process, else the edit button will still be disabled.

You can do this with following commands:

```
athakur:~/Downloads$ ps -eaf | grep shutter
athakur  13246  1815  2 22:53 tty2     00:00:13 /usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/shutter
athakur  14467  8059  0 23:01 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto shutter
athakur:~/Downloads$ kill -9 13246
athakur:~/Downloads$ shutter
```

Kill the process that's running `/usr/bin/shutter`. Now start shutter program again (It will again load the plugins required) and now the edit button should be enabled.