# Shutter in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, shutter

I loved the edit function in Shutter on Ubuntu 16.04/17.04/17.10 but now in 18.04 it says libgoo-canvas-perl needs to be installed - which is not available in 18.04.

Is there a PPA or how can I fix this?

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029085/how-to-enable-the-edit-button-in-shutter and please mark https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shutter/+bug/1767807 as "affects me too"!

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution on this blog: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/04/fix-edit-option-disabled-shutter-ubuntu-18-04/

Tested and works just fine.

Comment: And for missing icon in indicators? The package libgtk2-appindicator-perl is no more available in Ubuntu 18.04...