# Unable to locate package flameshot

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I tried to install Flameshot, but got an error saying `Unable to locate package flameshot` .

```
(base) kong:~$ sudo apt install flameshot
[sudo] password for kong: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package flameshot
```

Results of `lsb_release -a` :

```
(base) kong:~$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:printing-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:printing-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want install the *Flameshot* on *Ubuntu 16.04* you can simply **build it from the source**.

To do that, firstly you need to install these build tools:

```
sudo apt install g++ build-essential qt5-default qt5-qmake qttools5-dev-tools
sudo apt install libqt5dbus5 libqt5network5 libqt5core5a libqt5widgets5 libqt5gui5 libqt5svg5-dev
sudo apt install git openssl ca-certificates
```

And after that download the sources and install them:

```
git clone https://github.com/lupoDharkael/flameshot.git && cd flameshot
mkdir build && cd build
qmake ../
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.
Just a additional info for future readers:

To start:

From terminal - 

``` flameshot ``` there will be an icon on the top bar.

Answer (score 4):

According to https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=flameshot&searchon=names

the `flameshot` package is only available for Ubuntu release 18.04LTS or later.

Comment: Thanks for the information walt.